# DivestOS Mobile recovery image gives error on Heimdall

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, heimdall

my model is Samsung Note 3 SM-N9005 (https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/), the first time I used Heimdall I could succesfully flash the recovery image from https://divestos.org/pages/devices (https://divestos.org/mirror.php?base=LineageOS&f=hlte/divested-18.1-20240208-dos-hlte-recovery.img), now in download mode is current binary: custom and system status: custom , but when I go into recovery mode I get the standard one without install.
So I thought that the recovery partition got overwritten by the subsequent boots and I tried to flash it again to then immediately boot from recovery, but Heimdall keeps giving me ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer, even if I can download PIT with no problems.
I've tried this on Windows 10, 8.1 and 7 with the same result.
Also I have tried Odin on Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, in both device get added in Odin in Download Mode, but it crashes when trying to flash recovery img.
Please give me some help,
Thanks